# How do I check the size of the android app I'm working on in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-play

If I ever put it on the play store, what would it say under the size of the app? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Build` your project. then see the following path,

```
YOUR_PROJECT_LOCATION_DIRECTORY\PROJECT_NAME\app\build\outputs\apk
```

Now you can see `app-debug.apk` , then

You can find size of the `apk` file (`Right Click -> Properties`)

Answer (score 0):

Build APK
there you can see the size of App

Comment: While correct, you can mention where the APK is located.

Comment: it's in- YourAppFolder\app\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 0):

for appstore ,apps must be released and signed apk.